# Java maven not using the correct jdk. How can I specifiy or change which jdk it uses?

Tags: java, maven

My project requires me to use the var keyword which was added in java 13 however it keeps saying var cannot be resolved to type. I am using visual studio code as my IDE if that is of any importance

My current jdk is openjdk 17.0.5 2022-10-18. My JAVA_HOME environment is up to date so its not that. So any fixes would be helpful.

Comment: You have to configure the source and target compiler version in the `maven-compiler-plugin` in your pom.xml. If for example the source version is set to 11 then it doesn't matter which JDK you use, the compiled will only accept Java 11 language.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to configure to use JDK 11 or even higher is first to use a most recent version of the maven-compiler-plugin:

```
  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.10.1</version>
        </plugin>
        ..
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
```

You can now configure the used language level (needed JDk minimum) either via properties like this (definition of the encoding just as an example what should be defined as well). The `<maven.compiler.release>11</maven.compiler.release>` defines it via the `--release` option of the JDK compiler. This means you have to use at minimum JDK 11. If you like to use Language level 17 you simply change that to 17.

```
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.release>11</maven.compiler.release>
  </properties>
```

An alternative is to use the configuration directly to the maven-compiler-plugin like this:

```
  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.10.1</version>
          <configuration>
           <release>11</release>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        ..
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
```